# An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean MenuBean

Tags: java, arraylist, postconstruct

The problem comes when i'm try to convert from postgreSQL to mySQL and when i'm loggin into application. An error shown as below

```
    package com.salam.his.bean;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.annotation.Resources;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
    import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuItem;
    import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultSubMenu;
    import org.primefaces.model.menu.DynamicMenuModel;
    import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel;

    import com.salam.his.dao.CustomMenu;
    import com.salam.his.dao.MenuDAO;
    import com.salam.his.dao.MenuDAOImpl;
    import com.salam.his.dao.RolesMenuDAO;
    import com.salam.his.dao.RolesMenuDAOImpl;
    import com.salam.his.dao.UsersMenuDAO;
    import com.salam.his.dao.UsersMenuDAOImpl;
    import com.salam.his.dao.UsersRolesDAO;
    import com.salam.his.dao.UsersRolesDAOImpl;
    import com.salam.his.entities.Menu;
    import com.salam.his.entities.RolesMenu;
    import com.salam.his.entities.UsersMenu;
    import com.salam.his.entities.UsersRoles;
    import com.salam.his.util.SessionUtils;
    import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils;

    @ManagedBean(name = "menuBean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class MenuBean {

        private MenuModel model;
        private Collection<Menu> listOfParentMenu = null;
        private Collection<Menu> listOfParentMenuForUsers = null;
        private Menu listMenuById = null;
        private List<RolesMenu> listOfRolesMenu = null;
        private List<RolesMenu> listOfAllRolesMenuForUsers = null;
        private List<UsersMenu> listOfUsersMenu = null;
        private List<UsersMenu> listOfAllUserMenuForUsers = null;
        private List<UsersRoles> listOfUsersRoles = null;
        private MenuDAO menuDAO;
        private RolesMenuDAO rolesMenuDAO;
        private UsersMenuDAO usersMenuDAO;
        private UsersRolesDAO usersRolesDAO;
        UsersMenu userMenu = new UsersMenu();

        int userId = SessionUtils.getUserId();

        public MenuBean() { 

            // HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getUserId();
            model = new DynamicMenuModel();

            usersRolesDAO = new UsersRolesDAOImpl();
            rolesMenuDAO = new RolesMenuDAOImpl();
            usersMenuDAO = new UsersMenuDAOImpl();
            menuDAO = new MenuDAOImpl();

            DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
            DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();

            listOfUsersRoles = usersRolesDAO.getListUsersRolesByUserId(userId);
            listOfUsersMenu = usersMenuDAO.getUsersMenuById(userId);

            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listOfUsersRoles)) {
                listOfParentMenu = new ArrayList<Menu>();
                listOfAllRolesMenuForUsers = new ArrayList<RolesMenu>();
                for (UsersRoles ur : listOfUsersRoles) {
                    int rolesId = ur.getRolesId();
                    listOfRolesMenu = rolesMenuDAO.getListRolesMenuByRoleId(rolesId);
                    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listOfRolesMenu)) {
                        for (RolesMenu rm : listOfRolesMenu) {
                            int menuId = rm.getMenuId();
                            menuDAO = new MenuDAOImpl();
                            Menu m = menuDAO.getMenuById(menuId);

                            if (m.getParentId() == 0) {
                                listOfParentMenu.add(m);
                            }

                            listOfAllRolesMenuForUsers.add(rm);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listOfUsersMenu)){
                listOfParentMenuForUsers = new ArrayList<Menu>();
                listOfAllUserMenuForUsers = new ArrayList<UsersMenu>();
                for(UsersMenu um : listOfUsersMenu){
                    int menuId = um.getMenuId();
                    menuDAO = new MenuDAOImpl();
                    Menu menu = menuDAO.getMenuById(menuId);

                    if(menu.getParentId() == 0){
                        listOfParentMenuForUsers.add(menu);
                    }

                    listOfAllUserMenuForUsers.add(um);
                }
            }

            List<RolesMenu> rMenu = new ArrayList<RolesMenu>(listOfAllRolesMenuForUsers);
            List<UsersMenu> uMenu = new ArrayList<UsersMenu>(listOfAllUserMenuForUsers);

            List<CustomMenu> union2 = new ArrayList<CustomMenu>(rMenu);
            List<CustomMenu> different = new ArrayList<CustomMenu>(uMenu);
            different.removeAll(rMenu);

            if(different.size() > 0){
                union2.addAll(different);
            }

            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listOfParentMenu)) {
                for (Menu parentMenu : listOfParentMenu) {
                    submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
                    int menuId = parentMenu.getMenuId();
                    submenu.setLabel(StringUtils.capitalize(parentMenu.getMenuName()));
                    List<Menu> listMenu = menuDAO.getListOfMenuByParent(menuId);

                    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listMenu)) {
                        for (Menu childMenu : listMenu) {
                            for(CustomMenu rm : union2){
                                if(rm.getMenuId() == childMenu.getMenuId()){
                                    item = new DefaultMenuItem();
                                    item.setValue(StringUtils.capitalize(childMenu.getMenuName()));
                                    item.setOutcome(childMenu.getUrl().substring(14));
                                    submenu.addElement(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    model.addElement(submenu);
                }
            }

            List<Menu> roleMenu = new ArrayList<Menu>(listOfParentMenu);
            List<Menu> usersMenu = new ArrayList<Menu>(listOfParentMenuForUsers);

            List<Menu> union = new ArrayList<Menu>(usersMenu);
            union.addAll(roleMenu);

            List<Menu> intersection = new ArrayList<Menu>(usersMenu);
            intersection.retainAll(roleMenu);

            if(intersection.size() > 0){
                union.removeAll(intersection);
            }else{
                union.removeAll(roleMenu);
            }

            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(union)){
                for(Menu m : union){
                    submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
                    int menuId = m.getMenuId();
                    submenu.setLabel(StringUtils.capitalize(m.getMenuName()));
                    List<Menu> listMenu = menuDAO.getListOfMenuByParent(menuId);

                    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listMenu)) {
                        for (Menu childMenu : listMenu) {
                            for(UsersMenu rm : listOfAllUserMenuForUsers){
                                if(rm.getMenuId() == childMenu.getMenuId()){
                                    item = new DefaultMenuItem();
                                    item.setValue(StringUtils.capitalize(childMenu.getMenuName()));
                                    item.setOutcome(childMenu.getUrl().substring(14));
                                    submenu.addElement(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    model.addElement(submenu);
                }
            }       
        }

        public String getMenuById(int menuId) {
            menuDAO = new MenuDAOImpl();
            listMenuById = menuDAO.getMenuById(menuId);
            String menuName = listMenuById.getMenuName();
            return menuName;
        }

        public MenuModel getModel() {
            return model;
        }
    }
```

This is code for MenuBean. The error show after i'm convert database from postgresql to mysql. I need help. Thanks.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:177)
at com.salam.his.bean.MenuBean.<init>(MenuBean.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
... 56 more
```

The errors shown is Cant instantiate class: com.salam.his.bean.MenuBean.

Comment: listOfAllRolesMenuForUsers or listOfAllUserMenuForUsers can be null

Comment: thanks for give a hint. I just change null to new Arraylist<>(); problem solved.